Mesh Distorted when Switching to UV Editing
I'm new to Blender and will try my best to describe what's going on with my object.  I created a mesh rock generated object and applied a procedural asteroid material to it.

When I select it and click on UV Editing, the object gets distorted and the selection around the object is large and jagged.

It should look like this:

I'm using Blender Version 4.2.3LTS.  Is there a setting that I have turned off?  Any help would be much appreciated.


Thanks,
Don

Hello could you please show your modifiers stack? You probably have a Subdivision Surface then a Displace modifier?

Yes, just added screen shots.

if you want your object to be high in polygons like in your 3rd image you need to apply the Subdivision Surface modifier, but it will make the object heavier and harder to model, it really depends on your project
